# Is it possible to reduce lines of the code from sort helper functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a feature that requires sort/filter functionalities.
It's simple to do with helper functions to define your own way for both sorting and filtering. Suppose a GitHub case (and suppose the code below are all runnable)

```
compareRepoByModifiedTimeAscending (a, b) {
  return a.timestamp > b.timestamp ? 1 : 0
}

compareRepoByModifiedTimeDesending (a, b) {
  return a.timestamp > b.timestamp ? 0 : 1
}

compareRepoByOwnerNameAscending (a, b) {
  return a.ownerName > b.ownerName ? 1 : 0
}

compareRepoByOwnerNameDesending (a, b) {
  return a.ownerName > b.ownerName ? 0 : 1
}

....
```

I cound have many (and maybe too much) simple helper functions like this, and actually, the structure of them are very similar. Is it possible to find a way to minify the code base except using `switch`?

BTW, you are welcome to edit my question description and title if you think you can make it more general.

Comment: A comparison function must return `<0`, `0` or `>0`, not just `1` or `0`…!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [currying function](https://medium.com/@kevincennis/currying-in-javascript-c66080543528#.1ieb8tdbf) that will bind *key to sort on* and *order of sorting* and return a generic sort function.

```js
function sortByString(key, asc) {
  asc = asc ? 1 : -1;
  return function(a, b) {
    return a[key] > b[key] ? -1 * asc : a[key] < b[key]: 1 * asc: 0
  }
}
```

Sample:

```js
function sortByString(key, asc) {
  asc = asc ? 1 : -1;
  return function(a, b) {
    return a[key] > b[key] ? -1 * asc : a[key] < b[key] ? 1 * asc : 0
  }
}

var obj = [];

// Create a dummy list of objects
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  obj.push({
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    i: i * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  })
}
console.log(obj)
obj.sort(sortByString("i", 1))
console.log(obj)
obj.sort(sortByString("i", 0))
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a more generic comparison function accepting two extra arguments: name of the property to compare (`propName`) and sort `order`.

```
function compareRepo (propName, order, a, b) {
    // You may want to check validity of inputs, or initialize with proper defaults.
    if (['timestamp', 'ownerName'].indexOf(propName) === -1)
        throw new Error('invalid property name used')

    if (order === 'asc')
        return a[propName] > b[propName] ? 1 : 0
    else
        return a[propName] > b[propName] ? 0 : 1
}
```